# Dynamically find indexof based on array of list of string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I slice string base on the example array of strings below

```
[
    'PAP02-123-101-000-000-000-000-0000-SP-01-01',
    'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUN-01-02',
    'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUT-01-01'
]
```

and here is the final output

```
SP-01-01
SUN-01-02
SUT-01-01
```

Here is what I can think of to achieve the desired output

```
const str = 'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUN-01-02';
const newStr = str.substring(str.indexof(str.match(/^(SP|SUP|SUN)$/)))
```

Comment: Are the strings always in the format: stuff-string-number-number?

Comment: most of the case, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split`, `reverse` and `destructure`.

*This approach works for any string because will get the last three occurrences regardless of each token's length.*

```js
var array = [
  'PAP02-123-101-000-000-000-000-0000-SP-01-01',     
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUN-01-02', 
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUT-01-01'
];

var result = array.map((s) => {
  let [a, b, c] = s.split('-').reverse();
  return `${c}-${b}-${a}`;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`/(SP|SUP|SUN|SUT)+-\d{2}-\d{2}/` matches all of your examples. See this [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/HqEXrU/2).

```js
[
  'PAP02-123-101-000-000-000-000-0000-SP-01-01', 
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUN-01-02', 
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUT-01-01'
].forEach(str=>console.log(str.match(/(SP|SUP|SUN|SUT)+-\d{2}-\d{2}/)[0]));
```

Comment: Using set `[]` instead of a group `()` or `(?:)` makes strings like `USP` match.

Answer (score 0):

Substring them:

```js
var array = [
  'PAP02-123-101-000-000-000-000-0000-SP-01-01',     
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUN-01-02', 
  'PAP02-123-102-000-000-000-000-0000-SUT-01-01'
];

var result = array.map(s => s.substr(35));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for these three items, you could just get the index of the match on /S.*/